# How to detect an audio has reaches 30 seconds into playing?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, java-metro-framework

I have an audio tag that streams music from a web url. Once the song gets to over 30 seconds i want to get it to run a piece of code. Whats the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a handler to the `timeupdate` event raised by the `audio` control. Inside the handler, look at the control's `currentTime` property.

```
var audioControl = document.getElementById('myaudio');
audioControl.ontimeupdate = function () {
    if (audioControl.currentTime >= 30) { 
        // do something
    }
}
```